# Gradient of vectors and matrices

Tags: vector-analysis

I am new into vector calculus and I want to calculate the following: $\nabla_c(-2x^TDc+c^Tc)=-2D^Tx+2c$.

I used the intuitive way for $u(c)=c^Tc$ and got

$u(c+h)=(c+h)^T(c+h)=u(c)+2h^Tc+h^Th$. $u(c+h)-u(c) = 2h^Tc+h^Th$.

The first term is linear in $c$ with factor $2h^T$ and the second term is quadratic, i.e. unimportant for small h. Therefore $u'(c)=2c$

I tried it the same way for $u(c)=-2x^TDc$ and got

$u(c+h)=-2x^TD(c+h)=-2x^TDc-2x^TDh=u(c)-2x^TDh$

So $u(c+h)-u(c)=-2x^TDh$ and for small $h$ it should be $u'(c)=-2x^TD$

What am I doing wrong in the first term?

Comment: You should end up with vectors that have the same shape, so you’ve mistakenly transposed one of them.

Comment: Okay I got it. Because $-2x^TDc$ is scalar, I can transpose it before I take the gradient.

Comment: That’s right. However, I prefer to represent the gradient of a scalar function as a *row* vector, e.g., $-2x^TD+2c^T$, so that applying it to a displacement becomes matrix multiplication. This also makes it identical to the differential and helps remind me that it’s a covector that transforms differently from a vector, but this all really comes down to a matter of convention.